# Does a QGraphicsView take ownership over its associated graphics scene?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I was wondering... if I allocate a graphics scene

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
```

and associate it with a graphics view

```
this->ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

does the graphics view take ownership of the scene? In other words, does the graphics view delete the scene in its destructor or should I delete the scene myself?

Comment: The type of `this->ui->graphicsView` is [`QGraphicsView`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html)`*`, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no**.
That's because Qt makes it possible to display one model (`QGraphicsScene` in this case) in many views which is a standard feature of every model/view framework.

Documentation of `QGrahpicsView::setScene()` lacks information about what happens to ownership of a scene but the situation is the same as with others views; for example from documentation of [`void QWebView::setPage ( QWebPage * page )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebview.html#setPage)

> The parent QObject of the provided page remains the owner of the object.
>   If the current document is a child of
>   the web view, it will be deleted.